# MySQL: GROUP BY + HAVING MAX(...) --- Why HAVING MAX(grade) will not return maximum grade?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

*Credit Leetcode 1112. Highest Grade For Each Student*

Requirement: Write a SQL query to find the highest grade with its corresponding course for each student. In case of a tie, you should find the course with the smallest course_id. The output must be sorted by increasing student_id.

The query result format is in the following example:

```
Enrollments table:
+------------+-------------------+
| student_id | course_id | grade |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2          | 2         | 95    |
| 2          | 3         | 95    |
| 1          | 1         | 90    |
| 1          | 2         | 99    |
| 3          | 1         | 80    |
| 3          | 2         | 75    |
| 3          | 3         | 82    |
+------------+-----------+-------+

Result table:
+------------+-------------------+
| student_id | course_id | grade |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 1          | 2         | 99    |
| 2          | 2         | 95    |
| 3          | 3         | 82    |
```

Why this cannot work?

```
select student_id, course_id, grade
from enrollments
group by student_id
having max(grade)
order by student_id
```

I thought the return should be {"headers": ["student_id", "course_id", "grade"], "values": [[1, 2, 99], [2, 2, 95], [3, 3, 82]]}; however, the actual return is {"headers": ["student_id", "course_id", "grade"], "values": [[1, 1, 90], [2, 2, 95], [3, 1, 80]]}.

Thank you so much if anyone can help me!

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you think that this condition:

```
having max(grade)
```

is an instruction so that only the rows that have the max grade for each `studentid` should be returned.
This is not what a `HAVING` clause does.
It is a way to filter aggregated data after aggregation is done when it is used after a `GROUP BY` clause.
The `HAVING` clause accepts 1 or more boolean expressions which evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. 
So in this case `max(grade)` is not a boolean expression (although for MySql any numeric expression can be used in the place of a boolean one).

I understand that you want in the results the rows with the max grade of each `studentid`.
This can be done in the most efficient and performant way with window functions in MySQL 8.0: `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` if you want ties returned also:

```
select e.student_id, e.course_id, e.grade
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by student_id order by grade desc) rn
  from Enrollments
) e
where e.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75de4950e30144d27723d85dbdcec844).
Results:

```
| student_id | course_id | grade |
| ---------- | --------- | ----- |
| 1          | 2         | 99    |
| 2          | 2         | 95    |
| 3          | 3         | 82    |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical top-1-per-group problem. The key to solve this is that, since you want entire records, you should not think *aggregation*, but *filtering*.

I would recommend a correlated subquery for this. This is a portable solution, that works across most databases (including MySQL 5.x versions, that do not support window functions). With the right index in place, it is usually a very efficient approach.

```
select e.*
from enrollments e
where e.grade = (
    select max(e1.grade) 
    from enrollments e1 
    where e1.student_id = e.student_id
)
```

The index you want here is `(student_id, grade)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a subquery in the FROM clause to handle the double GROUP BY.

In the below query, the subquery gets the max grade per user, and then the outer enrollments table joins on both student_id and grade.  It then takes the first course_id in the outer query.

```
SELECT e.student_id, min(e.course_id) course_id, e.grade
FROM enrollments e
JOIN (
    SELECT student_id, max(grade) grade
    FROM enrollments
    GROUP BY student_id) g USING (student_id, grade)
GROUP BY e.studentId;
```